# Qmake scope syntax with "contains" function

Tags: qt, qmake

I wrote some qmake which looked like this:

```
contains( DEFINES, SOME_DEF ): DEFINES+=SOME_OTHER_DEF
```

The result was to ALWAYS execute what I thought was conditional, i.e. `DEFINES+=SOME_OTHER_DEF`

I changed the line to:

```
contains( DEFINES, SOME_DEF ){ DEFINES+=SOME_OTHER_DEF }
```

And it works as I expected now.  The thing is, I don't understand why I could not use the original syntax?

Here's the `contains` documentation (which doesn't address this detail regarding the use of `:`)
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#contains-variablename-value

Here is the scope documentation which seems to support what I was trying to do:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scopes-and-conditions

It says:

> You may... use the : operator to perform single line conditional
>   assignments.

I've definitely used the `:` in this manner before (but I guess not with `contains`?).  What am I failing to understand?

---

Additional info (responding to comment in a readable manner):

Test ran:

```
DEFINES+=A
DEFINES+=B
contains( DEFINES, A ) : contains( DEFINES, B ) : message( 1 )
contains( DEFINES, A ) : contains( DEFINES, C ) : message( 2 )
contains( DEFINES, A ):contains( DEFINES, B ):message( 3 )
contains( DEFINES, A ):contains( DEFINES, C ):message( 4 )
```

Result:

```
Project MESSAGE: 1
Project MESSAGE: 3
```

So it's not white space.

I think my question was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's about space. Seems following should work but I'm not sure

```
contains( DEFINES, SOME_DEF ):DEFINES+=SOME_OTHER_DEF
```

As I got it it's designed to be used as logical AND operator.

```
conditionA:conditionB {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  That could be it.  I'll test that out.  My understanding is it's supposed to be a shorthand conditional operator (it's akin to : in python) with the useful side effect of acting like a logical AND.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, that can't be the problem because it's a "false positive" issue. It executes the line when it should not rather than the other way around.

Comment: I'm thinking that if we do consider it a logical AND, the trouble may just be that there is no "short circuit".  In languages which don't short circuit, your combined statements execute even when a prior one logically negates the purpose of trying the next.  That would explain this.

Comment: False positive is clear for me. It just executes nothing before the space by condition and all after the space.

Comment: I think my problem my not be syntax after all, but in a logical complication with the way qmake executes multiple passes.  The white shouldn't matter.  Check my revised post.